# validateRequest="false" not working, even with requestValidationMode="2.0"

Tags: asp.net, azure, wif

I have an ASP.NET Web Site running in Visual Studio dev-fabric (azure project) and am using ACS and WIF. My authentication process isn't working because after I login I get this:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (wresult="<t:RequestSecurityTo...").
```

The documentation states that I need to add

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

and

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

And I did - but I'm still getting the error. I've also added validateRequest="false" at the page level. But nada - still getting the same error.

These steps seem to have fixed the issue for other posters - is it something to do with running in dev-fabric perhaps?

Comment: Are you posting to a page outside of the application?

Comment: why don't you use a requestsValidationType instead? http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SyntaxC4.WindowsAzure.ACSManagement.Mvc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hadn't realised, but I'd accidentally added these settings within a location tag created by WIF:

```
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
      <!-- wrong! -->
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
      <!-- right! -->
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
```

Comment: If i had a nickle for everytime i had this happen... Anyway here is a useful link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-identity-foundation-wif-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client-wresult-quot-lt-t-requestsecurityto-quot.aspx, also you can accept your own answer.