# "A potentially dangerous Request.Path found..." on .NET 4 with requestValidationMode="2.0" and validateRequest="false" set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, web-config

I'm attempting to circumvent the error message that .NET throws when you try and submit HTML:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

Having read the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773942/validaterequest-false-not-working-even-with-requestvalidationmode-2-0), web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>

        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>

        <pages validateRequest="false">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I type in HTML, I'm still getting the error though. I'm running a .NET 4, MVC 2 application just using the Visual Studio development server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, just read a blog here: http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2011/08/26/a-potentially-dangerous-request-value-was-detected-from-the-client.aspx

It talks of adding another attribute on your actions, `[ValidateInput(false)]`, which funnily enough, I haven't seen mentioned on any of the similar questions on SO.

I added the attribute to my BaseController, of which all controllers in my application inherit from and it immediately started working.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    // code here
}
```

Note: I still needed to include both:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

and

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

in the web config.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clean rebuild on the solution, and if needed close visual studio and clear your temporary ASP.NET files. If you have `ValidateRequest` set to false, then it's probably a caching issue or your DLL is out of sync.

As ajbeaven mentioned, you may also want to try adding the `ValidateInput` attribute to your controller class.

One of the above suggestions should definitely resolve your issue.